# How to upload a file to aws ec2 amazon linux 2 with POST request from any user local machine

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nodejs-server

I created a Nodejs server, that accepts files from user, and im stroing those file to a cms, so that i can generate the file link, and after the file link has been created, i wrote a fucntion, that deletes the file by using the file directory and file name.

I works my local machine, but after putting it on my ec2 amazon linux 2 server, when i make the post request, from postman, i dont get any response.

I don't know if it has to do it permission issue, but if there is someone that can help me, please do. because then ill have no choice than to choose another plaform to run my nodejs server.

I don't know if it has to do it permission issue, but if there is someone that can help me, please do. because then ill have no choice than to choose another plaform to run my nodejs server.

Comment: just for my curiosity, why not you are using multer package and directly uploading file to s3 which is more scalable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your EC2 instance is in a public subnet?
Did you configured the security groups on the instance properly?

Follow [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-http-https-ec2/) for a complete overview of how to configure your AWS environment to expose a web server from an EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you very much, i was able to solve the problem with the info you gave me.
Now I have fully configured the security group on the instance properly, and it is running now.